# How can I search a specific element and prints its value beneath it in a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

The sample CSV file looks like following:

```
aa  danny  james    
1   3      6    

aa  bla h  mno  
1   3      6    

aa  danny  james    
1   10     15
```

I want to read this CSV file and prints output in the following form :

```
line number  james  danny
2            6      3
7            15     10
```

I tried using re.search to start finding the element having value 'Danny' but it came out as error.

```
import csv, re

file_location=r'D:\\'

spamReader = csv.reader(open(file_location))
for row in spamReader:
    if re.search('Danny', row):
        print(row)
```

I am not sure if I have to use dictionary or something else to get the desired output.

Comment: Wait, do you want to output to a CSV or receive data from a CSV and manipulate it? The question isn't very clear on what you're trying to do either.

Comment: Hi. I want to receive data from the CSV file. i am able to read the elements 'james' and 'danny' and their values but I am not able to print the values under them.

Comment: So you're going through a CSV that is grouped in pairs of rows, and you're keeping track of any row that has a value for "danny" and "james".  Have you tried anything yet?  Even if it doesn't work at all, showing us that you've put effort in would be good.

Comment: Where on earth are you getting your "output" from? There are no references to a 2 or 7 in your CSV and "James Danny" Is in the input but is very arbitrary as to WHY it's in the output. What exactly are you trying to achieve with your input? How does it connect with your output?

Comment: @covertCoder things are a lot more clear if you're able to see the data the way that OP intends.  I submitted an edit that should make things much more clear.  In the meantime it might be worth hitting "edit" just to see what the data looks like.  The question is better defined than it looks at first glance.

Comment: Yes it makes sense now, thank you for the formatting Nolen.

Comment: Thanks Nolen. Sorry for the inconvenience. Actually, I am new to both python and stack overflow. I tried using re.search but it came out as error. Pls respond. Thanks.

Comment: @user1337072 no problem on the formatting.  You're getting downvoted because you haven't provided any code at all, even code that doesn't work.  If you could post what you tried with re.search (not the way that you want to go, for the record) or maybe give the csv module a try, I think you'd get better votes and a lot more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a particularly elegant solution, but was the easiest way I could come up with.

```
>>> with open('test.test') as f:
...     num_to_scores = {}
...     for linenum, line in enumerate(f):
...         splitline = line.split()
...         if 'danny' in line and 'james' in line:
...             store_next_vals = True
...             dannyloc, jamesloc = splitline.index('danny'), splitline.index('james')
...         else:
...             if store_next_vals:
...                 num_to_scores[linenum] = {"james":splitline[jamesloc], "danny":splitline[dannyloc]}
...                 store_next_vals = False
>>> with open('out.test', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('line number,james,danny\n')
...     for linenum in num_to_scores:
...         f.write('%d,%s,%s\n' % (linenum, num_to_scores[linenum]['james'], num_to_scores[linenum]['danny']))
>>> print open('out.test').read()
line number,james,danny
1,6,3
7,15,10
```